# How to pass function arguments to within?

Tags: r

I wonder how I can pass arguments of some function to a subpart of the function that uses with / within. e.g.:

```
  myfunction <- function(dataframe,col1,col2){

  res <- within(dataframe, somenewcol <-paste(col1,"-","col2",sep=""))

  return(res)


  }
```

where col1 and col2 are columns contained in the dataframe. What´s the correct way to pass the arguments col1 and col2 to the within expression? When I just try to use it, i get :

Error in paste(col1, "-", ,  : 
    object 'Some_passed_col' not found

Here´s an example:

```
   dataset <- data.frame(rnorm(20),2001:2020,rep(1:10,2))
   names(dataset) <- c("mydata","col1","col2")

   myfunction <- function(dataframe,arg1,arg2){
   res <- with(dataframe, onesinglecol <- paste(arg1,"-","arg2",sep=""))
   return(res)



   }
# call function
myfunction(dataset,col1,col2)
```

EDIT:

```
the following works for me now, but I cannot completely understand why... so any further explanation is appreciated:

 myfunction(dataset,arg1="col1",arg2="col2")
```

if I adjust

```
res <- with(dataframe, onesinglecol <- paste(get(arg1),"-",get(arg2),sep=""))
```

Comment: Complete mock-up example, please.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel, thx for the reminder, here you go...

Comment: Not reproducible. We need a mock dataset and a mock function.

Comment: Well, I did not set a seed, but apart from that the first two lines generate a dataset suitable for testing this..

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
   myfunction <- function(dataframe,arg1,arg2){
   dataframe["onesinglecol"] <- dataframe[[arg1]] -dataframe[[arg2]]
   return(dataframe) 
   }
```

And call it with character-valued column names rather than object names that are nowhere defined:

```
myfunction(dataset,"col1","col2")
       mydata col1 col2 onesinglecol
1   0.6834402 2001    1         2000
2   1.6623748 2002    2         2000
3  -0.5769926 2003    3         2000  .... etc
```

Comment: Thx works, just like my edit does. But here I do not understand the reasoning behind using these double [[]]... Could you please explain what they mean?

Comment: The "[[" operator returns the value of a list node, while the "[" operator returns a list that contains that value. The "value" is often a vector as in this case. Since Arithmetic operations work on vectors but not lists, in this instance you want the "[[" version of Extract.

Comment: If you still want to use within() then try:  myfunction <- function(dataframe,arg1,arg2){
  within(dataframe, "onesinglecol" <- get(arg1) - get(arg2) )
   }

Comment: Within is best saved for interactive use, not for use within another function.

Comment: @Hadley: No argument from me. I felt like I was turning around like a pretzel in order to come up with a "working" within-version.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is done via the ... directive:
E.g.:

```
myfunction <- function(dataframe, ...){

  var <- anotherfunction( arg1= 1, arg2 = 2 , ...)
  return(var)
}
```

... is a placeholder for additional arguments passed through to "anotherfunction".

Comment: `within()` doesn't work like that. `...` will just pass on extra arguments, whilst `within()` is expecting an R expression to evaluate. Indeed, `?within` says that `...` is for arguments to some **future** methods, so likely ignored when evaluating the expression. I admit the OP's Q was not very clear, hence no down vote from me on your answer, but it isn't an answer to this Q. In general though, yes, this is how you can pass on `...` in your own functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fact that `col1` and `col2` do not exist in `dataframe` (from your) nor in the user workspace.

Basically, `with()` and `within()` work like this:

```
> foo <- 10
> bar <- data.frame(FOO = 10)
> FOO + foo
Error: object 'FOO' not found
> with(bar, FOO + foo)
[1] 20
```

In the first case, `FOO` was not found as it is inside `bar`. In the second case, we set up an environment within which our expression is evaluated. Inside that environment `FOO` does exist. `foo` is also found in the workspace.

In your first example (please don't edit error messages etc, show us exactly what code you ran and what error was produced) either one `col1` or `col2` didn't exist in the environment created within which your expression was evaluated.

Further, you appear to want to store in `col1` and `col2` the *name* of a column (component) of your `dataframe`. DWin has shown you one way to use this information. An alternative maintaining the use of `within()` is to use `get()` like this:

```
res <- within(dataframe, somenewcol <- paste(get(col1), "-", get(col2), sep=""))
```

Why this works, as per your extra edit and quandary, is that `get()` returns the object *named* by it's first argument. `get("foo")` will return the object named `foo` (continuing from my example above):

> get("foo") ## finds foo and returns it
>   [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096007/is-there-a-better-way-to-access-these-variables-than-attach) 10

In your example, you have a data frame with names *inter alia* `"col1"` and `"col2"`. You changed your code to `get(arg1)` (where `arg1 <- "col1"`), where you are asking `get()` to return the object with name `"col1"` from the evaluation environment visible at the time your function is being evaluated. As your `dataframe` contained a `col1` component, which was visible because `within()` had made it available, `get()` was able to find an object with the required name and include it in the expression.

But at this point you are trying to jump through too many hoops because your questions haven't been specific. I presume you are asking this because of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096007/is-there-a-better-way-to-access-these-variables-than-attach) to your previous Q. That answer suggested a better alternative than `attach()`. But you weren't clear there what some arguments were or what your really wanted to do. If I had known now what you really wanted to do then I would have suggested you use DWin's Answer above.

You seem to not want to hard code the column/component names. If you could hard code, this would be the solution:

```
res <- within(dataframe, somenewcol <- paste(col1, "-", col2, sep = ""))
```

But seeing as you don't want to hard code you need a `get()` version or DWin's solution.

Comment: thx for the effort. And yes I want to prevent hardcoding the names of col1, col2.